# Coderbuddy and publishing on googleapp engine - Error 409: "appcfg rollback"

Tags: google-app-engine

I was using coderbuddy, and when I try to publish to google app, I receive this error:

Error 409

Another transaction by user ---- is already in progress for app: s~spigeo-app, version: 1. That user can undo the transaction with "appcfg rollback"

tried doing "appcfg rollback" on command prompt and received "Error 403: you do not have permission to modify this app"

I'm the only owner of the codes. Been stuck for a week; please advise, thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with coderbuddy, but have you tried to log in to https://appengine.google.com/ and check the permissions page?

Comment: yea, i have. it says "owner". the version is 1 though.

Comment: When doing the appcfg rollback, are you entering your Google Account password or the Application-specific password?

Comment: oh. google account password. is that wrong?

Comment: Yes, Google changed the authentication method for GAE some time ago. Go to your Google Account page at https://www.google.com/settings/ and click edit on the "Authorizing applications & sites" menu. You need to "Generate new application-specific password" and use that password instead when prompted by the appcfg. Let us know if this works. :)

Comment: hey Ibrahim, the section is greyed, so i cant create a password. but thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Is the problem solved? If you have found another correct solution for your problem, please post that as an answer so others having similar problem would know how to solve it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

coderbuddy has since fixed it, so it's no longer a problem. Just FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Error

`Another transaction by user ID is already in progress for app: b~GAE_PROECT_ID, version: 1. That user can undo the transaction with "appcfg rollback".`

Fix the error

`google_appengine/appcfg.py —oauth2 -A GAE_PROECT_ID rollback app_engine_installer/app_engine_project/app.yaml —noauth_local_webserver`